# Ubuntu not booting after dual installing with Windows XP SP2

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have 2 hard disk in my PC (First one was divided into 3 logical drives C:\, D:\ and E:\ and the secondary Hard disk was divided into 2 logical drives G:\ and H:\ ) The former one was running Windows XP installed in C drive with the FAT32 file system for the former and the latter was in NTFS.

I had some files in G:\ drive which i moved to H:\ drive before installing Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS through Boot CD. The installation was done with part of G:\ drive (with more than 300 GB) was used as root (/) file system with about 10 Gig and Swap space of 6 Gig.

After the installation, Ubuntu asked to reboot and also self ejected the disk from the tray. Post reboot, the dual boot is not seen and the PC loads into Windows XP SP2 and i cannot see the G and H Drive too.

What could have gone wrong ? I followed a thread on how to install with Windows XP and had cleared up the G:\ drive for that. Are my files in H:\ drive gone ?

Using Windows Disk Management tool i can still see the secondary hard drive as unallocated space together with the 500Gig (both G and H drive together). The Boot CD is also not showing up properly (shown as empty drive) from Windows XP now.

How am i to recover the H drive and then install Ubuntu properly ??

Answer (score 0):

please try instructions on following link and see if it solves your booting problem. [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

also you can't see the drives on which Linux is installed because it uses a different filesystem than windows. you need to install a software if you want to access those drives from Windows but that's not recommended because an accidental change of important files can blow up your Linux for good so you need to take precautions.